# Exclude javascript library from code completion in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

Is there a way to exclude a Javascript library from code completion in IntelliJ IDEA without excluding it from the module? If I exclude it from the module sources, Idea does not process it in artifacts anymore.

I need the Javascript library in deployment, but it pollutes auto-completion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution:

Right-click the Javascript file in project window, choose "Mark as plain-text". Also works for CSS.

Comment: what if I want to exclude all the files of this extension? (js in my case)